# Replace certain text string within quotation in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

For example:

> "I elaborate this as bla," Caesar said. Then, Alexis elaborate, "This only elaborate that bla."

I would like to replace all **elaborate** strings inside the quotation to become **describe**. Outside of quotation, the **elaborate** should stay as **elaborate**.

The text should become:

> "I describe this as bla," Caesar said. Then, Alexis elaborate, "This only describe that bla."

I have tried Smart Quotes and using `(^0147*)(elaborate)(*^0148)` in the Find. However it changes all three instances when I want to only find and replace two appearances.

In the sentence, it identifies the first and last quotation mark as the whole part instead of breaking it into two sentences within the quotation marks.

Comment: Is it a typo or do you have both `“` and `"` in the text,

Comment: Are you OK for a notepad++ solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing the word elaborate in a quoted string marked by Smart Quotes the Wildcard Find string should be: (^0147*)(elaborate)(*^0148)

If the strings are quoted using straight quotes the Find string should be: (^34*)(elaborate)(*^34)

The Wildcard Replacement string in both cases should be: \1describe\3

If your document has a combination of quoted strings using Smart and Straight quotation marks, as your supplied example does, you will have to run the Advanced Find & Replace using Wildcards twice.

Comment: It use the first and last quotation marks, thus replacing all three "elaborate"